# Codeigniter-restserver does not accept POST method CORS

Tags: rest, backbone.js, cordova, cors, codeigniter-restserver

I'm developing a REST API using **Codeigniter-restserver** for a mobile applications in **Phonegap**.

Since **Phonegap** loads `index.html` using `file://`, my API should support **CORS**. And I'm new to this **CORS**.

I've set headers in `libraries/REST_Controller.php`

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
```

And I'm using **Backbone.js**.

Here is my Controller

```
// This can be removed if you use __autoload() in config.php OR use Modular Extensions
require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class Prop extends REST_Controller
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
       parent::__construct(); 
       $this->load->database();
    }
    function property_get()
    {
        ...
    }    
    function property_post()
    {
    ...
    }
    function attach_image($file_type) 
    {
            if($this->post($file_type) != ""){
                    save_base64_image($file_type,$this->post($file_type));
                    $this->email->attach($_SESSION[$file_type]);
            }
    }       

    function property_delete()
    {
        ...
    }
function share_post()
    {       
    $email_id = $this->post('emailid');

    $config['mailtype'] = "html";
    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('myid@gmail.com', 'mobile app');
    $this->email->to($email_id); 

    $this->email->subject('subject');
    $this->email->message('message');   

    if ( ! $this->email->send() )
    {
        $this->response("Internal server error.", 500);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $result = new stdClass();
        $result->message = 'Email has been sent.';
        $this->response($result, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
    }        

    }

public function send_post()
{
    var_dump($this->request->body);
}


public function send_put()
{
    var_dump($this->put('foo'));
}
```

}

Here's my jQuery ajax call.

```
$.ajax( {
        url: PMSApp.apiUrl + "/share/format/json",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
})
.fail(function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
})
.always(function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

I'm able to access this `/share/format/json` API with POSTMAN, chrome extension, but not with `file://` or `localhost://`.

**EDIT:**

I've also tried changing `share_post()` to `share_gett()`, It worked. But i need it in POST.

I'm stuck on this for the past 48 hours. Tried many solutions, but nothing helped me with this issue. Please help me.

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: @Leandro phonegap has a feature to whiltelist your domain. it needs to be set in config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap provides option to whitelist your webservice domain. It is set up the access origin in config xml
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to start Chrome with Access-Control-Allow-Origin

This thread:
https://superuser.com/questions/384871/overriding-access-control-allow-origin-restriction-in-google-chrome

Check this tread:
[Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: Hi Aart, Thanks for your reply. Actually Im developing a Phonegap app. So i wont be able to set this option there.

Comment: I do this alot for Phonegap apps.
Just dont forget to edit the config.xml <access origin="*" />

Comment: Oh, i didn't know such option is there in Phonegap. I'll try it in that way. Thanks Bart :)